# How to easily generate unique strings in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, doxygen

I have a question!

I have an XML document that has sections and subsections. I am generating a Doxygen page out of it using `XSLTProc` and now I have a problem. When I generate a section name like this:

```
<xsl:template match="SECTION/SUBSECTION">
@subsection <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Then the first word of the title does not show up, because Doxygen expects the declaration in this way:

```
@subsection <subsectionname> <subsectiontitle>
```

So, the first word is automatically treated as the subsection name. Putting a randomly generated string there does not seem like a very simple task. I tried to put unique number instead, by using `<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[@col]) + 1"`, which worked as expected, but as it turns out, Doxygen does not accept numbers as subsection names. I also tried to strip white spaces of `"@title"` and use that as the subsection name, but XSLTProc complains that it was not an immediate child of `<xslt:stylesheet>`. How can I easily put some unique string there? It does not have to be meaningful text.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use the `generate-id()` function**.

```
<xsl:value-of select="generate-id(@title)"/>
```

**If you want the generated string to be more "readable", here is one way to do this**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(@title, generate-id(@title))"/>
```